# Exclude contents of folders with specific names

Tags: phpstorm

We have a folder structure like this for our translations:

```
en/
   |- translationFile1.xml
   |- translationFile2.xml
   |- translationFile3.xml
fr/
   |- translationFile1.xml
   |- translationFile2.xml
   |- translationFile3.xml
it/
   |- translationFile1.xml
   |- translationFile2.xml
   |- translationFile3.xml
```

We only ever have to work with the english versions of these files. The other languages usually clutter up the *Find in Path* results, so it would be useful if we can exclude the other folders automatically. Is it possible to automatically exclude files from folders that have specific names, like "fr" or "it"?

Comment: `Settings/Preferences | Directories` -- you can mark such folders as excluded there. Sadly, that cannot be done automatically for a brand new project (default settings for new projects) as that settings page is not available in "Settings for New Projects".

Comment: Another approach -- create **custom Scope** and include there only desired folders (or other way around -- exclude unwanted). Then you can use that scope when using "Find in Path". Good thing here, such Scope can be created and applied for brand new projects automatically (`File | Other Settings | Settings for New Projects...`)

Comment: Good options here, even if none of them are automated.

Comment: One more option: add `fr`, `it`, etc. to **Settings | Editor | File Types, Ignore files and folders**. This is a global option that will affect all projects. But note that ignored folders are hidden, i.e. you won't see them in the Project explorer

Comment: @lena By far the best suggestion! (I'd make it an answer if I was you) That's what I was looking for, even though I would've preferred to still be able to see the other files. It's incredibly rare for us to have to edit those though, so it should be fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `fr`, `it`, etc. to **Settings | Editor | File Types, Ignore files and folders**. This is a global option that will affect all projects. But note that ignored folders are hidden, i.e. you won't see them in the **Project** explorer